# How do i get a reference to an AuthenticationManager using a Spring java security configuration?

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, autowired

I’m using Spring 4.1.5.RELEASE and Spring Security 3.2.5.RELEASE.  I’m doing all security configuration through Java (as opposed to XML).  I’m struggling to get a reference to the `AuthenticationManager` for use with my custom usernamepassword authentication filter …

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.mainco", excludeFilters=@ComponentScan.Filter(Controller.class))
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String ROLE3 = "ROLE3";
    private static final String ROLE2 = "ROLE2";
    private static final String ROLE1 = "ROLE1";

    @Resource(name="userDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Resource(name="myAuthenticationSuccessHandler")
    private MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler authSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/403").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/ROLE1/**").hasRole(ROLE1)
                .antMatchers("/common/**").hasAnyRole(ROLE1, ROLE2, ROLE3)
                .antMatchers("/ROLE3/**").hasAnyRole(ROLE1, ROLE2, ROLE3)
                .antMatchers("/ROLE2/**").hasAnyRole(ROLE1, ROLE2)
                .antMatchers("/*/**").fullyAuthenticated()
            .and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .successHandler(authSuccessHandler)
            .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
            .and().csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean(name="passwordEncoder")
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new StandardPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public JSONUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() {
        final MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter authFilter = new MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter();
        authFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(authSuccessHandler);
        authFilter.setUsernameParameter("username");
        authFilter.setPasswordParameter("password");
        return authFilter;
    }
```

This configuration fails upon startup with the message

> “Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: authenticationManager must be specified”.

How do I get a reference to the `AuthenticationManager` for use with my filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `authenticationManagerBean()` method from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to expose `AuthenticationManager` as a bean like so:

```
@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```